# I am trying to do multiple(video and images each in seperate folder) uploads using multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer, cloudinary

Cloudinary configuration
The configuration works fine and i checked in the management console the uploaded videos are present there

But the multer is not working for videos

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
const cloudinaryStorage = require('multer-storage-cloudinary');
const storage1 = cloudinaryStorage({
    cloudinary,
    folder: 'bat1',
    allowedFormats: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'],
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        let buf = crypto.randomBytes(16); //generating random 16 Bytes
        buf = buf.toString('hex'); //Converting to hex will give 32 CHARACTERS & converting to string
        let uniqFileName = file.originalname.replace(/\.jpeg|\.jpg|\.png/ig, ''); //RegEx used to remove file expression
        uniqFileName += buf; //These CHARACTERS will be added to the filename
      //Even though the user creates file with same name it will not MATCH bcz of CHARACTERS
      cb(undefined, uniqFileName );
    }
  });

const storage2 = cloudinaryStorage({
    cloudinary,
    allowedFormats: ['mp4', 'webm', 'ogg'],
    params:{
        folder: 'bat1video',
        resource_type: 'video'
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        let buf = crypto.randomBytes(16);
        buf = buf.toString('hex'); 
        let uniqFileName = file.originalname.replace(/\.mp4|\.webm|\.ogg/ig, ''); 
        uniqFileName += buf; 
      cb(undefined, uniqFileName );
    }
  });

module.exports = {
    cloudinary,
    storage1,
    storage2
}
```

In the routes i am doing this
Can i use **upload1** and **upload2** like this or there should be only **one upload per file**
For the images it works fine but for the videos it doesn't

```
const { storage1, storage2 } = require('../cloudinary');
const upload1 = multer({ storage:storage1 });
const upload2 = multer({ storage:storage2 });
```

For the images it works fine

```
router.post('/', isLoggedIn, upload1.array('postImages', 4), asyncErrorHandler(fnc));
```

But for the video it doesn't .
The video is saved in the cloud multer gives `req.files` as undefined when accessed in the backend

```
router.post('/', isLoggedIn, upload1.array('postVideo', 4), asyncErrorHandler(fnc));
```